# Api call to upload file for article or page

Tags: api, shopify

i'm new here, and trying to understand from the docs how to upload images for articles/blog posts through the api.

I can see the "Asset" resource is it the one i have to deal with?

how is the file structure of the store bucket?

Image uploaded to the blog can be accessed through URI like this

http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/xxxxxxxxxxxx/files/wwb_drapers_large.jpg

Image uploaded as a theme asset  can be accessed through URI like this

http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/xxxxxxxxxxxx/assets/logo.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Asset resource would be the only API resource you can use to upload images.

While there is functionality through the admin interface to upload an image to an article, it is not exposed through the API. This only means that you can't use the API to upload files into the 'files' bucket. Instead, you'd use the Asset resource to upload the file to the 'assets' bucket.

See http://api.shopify.com/asset.html#update under the heading: 'Create a new image by providing a base64-encoded attachment' to create the asset. You can then use the 'public_url' attribute on the asset and use that within the article.